# Rails logger undefined method in controller, no issue in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

Pushing to my staging server (clone of production), I am getting the following Rails logger error that I do not see in production or development:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 274ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `debug=' for #<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x007fd1ca7fa0a0>):
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:26:in `create'
```

Running `rails console staging` let's me write to the log using Rails.logger.debug just fine, exactly as I am doing in the controller.

I am on the latest version of Rails 3 (3.2.18). I am using the baked in Rails logger, no third party logging services are in place.

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: try in terminal: `RAILS_ENV=staging rails c` and then `logger.debug 'check'`

Comment: @emaillenin here is the output, which also writes to my log file:

    irb(main):002:0> Rails.logger.debug 'check'
    => true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `debug=`; it's not a method. What you probably wanted to do is call the `debug` method and pass it the output you want:

```
logger.debug "Output content goes here"
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... long day. Thanks!